# could not resolve placeholder: Spring XML error

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am stuck up with the below mentioned exception. I tried most possible ways that I could. But they weren't helpful.

Is this issue because of any inappropriate jars?
is it due to multiple placeholders?

Please help me out. Hoping for a positive response.

Thanks and please let me know if there is anything else that i could share with you people for a better understanding.

```
[12/5/13 4:08:55:744 EST] 0000033e webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0}
                                 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Error initializing PuttPropertyFileReader; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Error registering bean with name 'customLog4jConfigurer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-context.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'logging.springlogfile'
                at com.lmig.putt.database.utils.PUTTPropertyFilePlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PUTTPropertyFilePlaceholderConfigurer.java:136)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:348)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:251)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:190)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1651)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:746)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:422)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:714)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1154)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1369)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:638)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:967)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:760)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1348)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2144)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:663)
                at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5323)
                at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5539)
                at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:677)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:621)
                at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1240)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
                at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
                at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
                at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
                at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
                at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
                at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
                at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
                at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
                at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
                at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
                at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:241)
                at com.ibm.ws.console.appdeployment.ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.execute(ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.java:564)
                at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1188)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:763)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:454)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:919)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1016)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1384)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:193)
                at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1188)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:763)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:454)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:92)
                at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:950)
                at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:499)
                at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:320)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:919)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1016)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:895)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
                at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
                at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
                at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
                at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
                at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
                at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
                at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
                at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
                at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
                at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
                at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
                at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1659)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Error registering bean with name 'customLog4jConfigurer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-context.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'logging.springlogfile'
                at com.lmig.putt.database.utils.PUTTPropertyFilePlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PUTTPropertyFilePlaceholderConfigurer.java:176)
                at com.lmig.putt.database.utils.PUTTPropertyFilePlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PUTTPropertyFilePlaceholderConfigurer.java:132)
                ... 105 more
```

application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">

    <bean id="properyFilePlaceholderConfigurer" class="com.lmig.putt.database.utils.PUTTPropertyFilePlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="location">
                <value>/WEB-INF/config/PuttWebConfiguration.xml</value>
            </property>

        </bean>

 <bean id="customLog4jConfigurer" class="com.lmig.putt.database.utils.Log4JConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>/WEB-INF/config/app-log4j.properties</value>
        </property>
        <property name="log4JProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="ROOTLEVEL">${logging.rootlogger}</prop>
                <prop key="APPLEVEL">${logging.applogger.level}</prop>
                <prop key="CONSOLETHRESHOLD">${logging.consolethreshold}</prop>
                <prop key="SPRINGLOGLEVEL">${logging.spring.level}</prop>
                <prop key="EMAIL">${logging.email}</prop>
                <prop key="SPRING_LOGFILE">${logging.springlogfile}</prop>
                <prop key="ENV">${logging.environment}</prop>
                <prop key="MAXFILESIZE">${logging.maxfilesize}</prop>
                <prop key="MAXBACKUPINDEX">${logging.maxbackupindex}</prop>     
                <prop key="APP_LOGFILE">${logging.puttdblogfile}</prop>
                <prop key="SYS_LOGFILE">${logging.systemlogfile}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

ProjectWebConfiguration.xml

```
<!--Log4J Configuration  -->
            <item key="logging.environment" value="local"/>

            <item key="logging.rootlogger" value="INFO"/>
            <item key="logging.applogger.level" value="DEBUG"/>
            <item key="logging.spring.level" value="INFO"/>
            <item key="logging.consolethreshold" value="OFF"/>
            <item key="logging.email" value="vetree@salemns.com"/>

            <item key="logging.springlogfile" value="/home/vetree/spring.log"/>
            <item key="logging.systemlogfile" value="/home/vetree/sys.log"/>
            <item key="logging.puttdblogfile" value="/home/vetree/smart.log"/>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>PUTT</display-name>

 <context-param>
  <param-name>log4ConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
  <!-- Log4jConfigListener also tries to
        set the webAppRootKey. solve this by adding the following statements in web.xml -->
 <context-param>
  <param-name>log4jExposeWebAppRoot</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

Comment: Did you define logging.springlogfile property in your app-log4j.properties?

Comment: If by STS you mean Spring tool suite, then NO I am not using one.

Comment: @KeerthiRamanathan, Yes I have defined the property in app-log4j.properties

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the context namespace to your Spring Configuration, then define the location of the property placeholder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/WEB-INF/config/app-log4j.properties" />
```

Please note that the version of the context namespace may differ for you.  It is most easily added using STS which will add the import for you into the configuration file.